# $V(x)=V_0\sin^2(k_0x) $ potential, 1 dimensional

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, potential, schroedinger-equation

If I have a potential like this:

$$V(x)=V_0\sin^2(k_0x) $$ where $k_0^2=2m/h^2E_*$

how can I prove that the wavefunctions are:

$\Psi_q(x)=e^{iqx}u_q(x)$ where $qe[-k_0,k_0]$ and $u_q(x)$ is periodic

What is the differential equation that $u_q(x)$ satisfies?

Comment: Why don't you just plug it in the Schrödinger's equation? I'm assuming the problem is single-particle and non-relativistic.

Comment: yup its single particle

Answer (score 3):

For the first part, you would use [Bloch's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch%27s_theorem).

For the second part, why don't you plug it into the Schrodinger Equation and see what happens?

Comment: Yup , that makes sense, however I am not quiet sure that I can use it, could you be a little more helpfull with the computations?

Comment: Well, this seems like a pretty standard "[homework-style](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/715/157014)" problem, and giving complete answers to them is generally frowned upon here. Besides, it's not particularly hard. If you need to know if you can use Bloch's theorem, check what requirements need to be satisfied and see if your Hamiltonian satisfies them. Good luck!

Comment: Its for a module I 've been studying from past exams. I couldnt find any solved problems like this  and thats why I tried here. Didnt know this rule, thanks